# jQuery validate onfocusout

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate this form located here: http://jsfiddle.net/PEmFH/8/
I want to validate on onfocusout (validate every time the user leaves the field). It is not working for some reason.

Please find the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PEmFH/11/

Comment: which plugin you used? do you include it?

Comment: You haven't loaded the jQuery validation plugin in your jsFiddle (I assume it's that one you want to use when you call .validate().

Comment: Title says "on key up", question says "onfocusout" - which is it?

Comment: Seems to work fine [with the plugin included](http://jsfiddle.net/PEmFH/9/). e.g. entering an invalid email address, and click out.

Comment: Check out this plugin I'm working on...Seems like this is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/ZsS2D/

Comment: Did you perhaps expected the `required` validation to trigger? Please note in the documentation: `If nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was already marked as invalid.`

Comment: @theCodeParadox: I did not use any plugin, please find the updated fiddle.

Comment: @primavera133: I had included it already.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Sorry for the confusion, please check the edits.

Comment: @HenryP It works fine but firebug is giving me an error:
this[0] is undefined
http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js
Line 101
Also, could you tell me what code should I write in jQuery so as to compare the email addresses and display error right away if they do not match?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "element" method that returns true or false if a element is valid or not
http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/

This is the way i solved:

```
$.each($('#form input[type="text"], #form textarea'), function(index, control) {
    $(control).focusout(function() {
        if ($('#form').validate().element(this)) {
           //Code for show a valid message or remove a invalid message                     
        } else {
           //Code for show a invalid message
        }
    });                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help too

```
//This is used to validate the Length Exceeded to Account number text box.
    $('#AccountName').focusout(function () {
        var currentVal = $.trim($('#AccountName').val()).toLocaleLowerCase().length;
        if (currentVal > 50) {
            alert("Length Exceeded");
            return false;
        }
    });
```